# Scroll content of second div to end of first div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed div on top of my page (it gets fixed only when we scroll upto it) containing base information and a dropdown for selection and another div below it containing the content.

Now when a user selects a content name from this drop down, that section should expand and page should scroll upto a level that the heading of this expanded section should start appearing exactly where the fixed div ends.
I am able to scroll this section to top of page using

```
function ScrollToElement(element) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + element).position().top
        }, 'slow');
    }
```

but I want to scroll it to end of first div not top of the page.
I have tried adding/subtracting the height/outerheight of the fixed div but that does not works.

Please help me in achieving this.

I have created a fiddle for it : http://jsfiddle.net/eranjali08/b7W95/

Comment: Please provide the relevant code, or a minimal demo to reproduce what you have so far. do you expect us to create the entire webpage as you wish from the scratch..?

Comment: @Kisspa I have added the jsFiddle

Comment: @TilwinJoy I have added the jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#searchbycharacter a').on('click', function() {
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');   
    var target = $('#'+rel).offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':target-50+'px'});
  });
});
```

here is demo link of jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/JWJ5N/12/

Comment: in the fiddle, the concerned div id going behind the fixed div. I want it to come right below the end of fixed div

Comment: I am using something like this

         $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#" + element).position().top - $('#topContainer').height() + 'px'
            }, 'slow');

where <b>#topContainer</b> is the name of fixed div but this is not working. In fact, when I write this the page doesn't scrolls at all :( 

<b>P.S.</b> I can't use offset() as it fails in IE8 so I am using position.

Comment: were you able to figure out this issue with jsfiddle?

Answer (score -1):

This might be help you, You can use `data-target` 
Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/JWJ5N/9/)

Comment: I am using something like this

         $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#" + element).position().top - $('#topContainer').height() + 'px'
            }, 'slow');

where <b>#topContainer</b> is the name of fixed div but this is not working. In fact, when I write this the page doesn't scrolls at all :( 

<b>P.S.</b> I can't use offset() as it fails in IE8 so I am using position.

Comment: were you able to figure out this issue with jsfiddle?